# Nested promise catch not executing

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function which takes a function that returns a Promise and I am calling it like so:

```
const test = (prom) => {
  prom()
  .then(() => console.log('top level then'))
  .catch(() => console.log('top level catch'));
};
test(() => new Promise(() => fetch()
  .then(() => console.log('inner level then'))
));
```

The `fetch()` call will return an error because I'm not actually fetching anything but the top level catch is not running - why is that?

The behaviour I'm looking for is that everytime the `prom` Promise resolves, the top level then will run and everytime it rejects, the top level catch will run (in addition to any inner level then and catches).

Comment: `fetch()` already returns a promise so there's no need to wrap it in another one. This is a classic example of the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: I'd even go so far as to see this is a duplicate. Not so much the question but in applying the answers (by unwrapping the `fetch()` promise), your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

It is because your new promise doesn't resolve or reject anything.

```
test(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => fetch()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('inner level then');
    resolve();
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('inner level catch');
    reject();
  })
));
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern.  There's no reason to wrap `fetch()` in a new promise.  Just `return fetch().then()`.  No need to make a new promise.